# Issue with wget, not downloading PDF even with -A.pdf

Tags: linux, macos, unix

very new to this... apologies for mistakes/stupidity in advance.

Trying to use wget on mac to download PDF's from a list. I have a text file of DOI's (e.g. 10.1046/j.1365-294X.2001.01258.x), essentially I want to enter these DOI's into sci-hub.io and download the corresponding PDF. I have appended the DOI's to become a legitimate web address (e.g. http://sci-hub.io/10.1046/j.1365-294X.2001.01258.x). These work when entered manually into chrome, but not with wget to automate the process.

Tried: 
wget -i file.txt

wget -A.pdf -i file.txt

wget -A.pdf -erobots=off -i file.txt

All of these still return files containing html info.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be not you doing something wrong, but the site itself which could forbid "bad" user-agents to prevent web scraping.

Comment: I just looked at the example page you gave - it is a HTML page with pdf file embedded in `<iframe>` tag. Look at the source code.

Comment: Thanks Pumbo! Your time and comments are appreciated!